# On click submit button state change in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, submit, onsubmit, states

I want to change to state of the submit button when a user clicks on that I want to make these transitions on that button.

```
Text change to "submitting..." and state of that submit button becomes "disabled"
```

I know how to do this with Jquery something like:

Let's say that the button has a #derp id.

```
$("#derp").click(function(){
   this.toggleClass("pressed");
});
```

Basicly this will add or remove the "pressed" class from the item based on its state. Just add the css for .pressed and you're ready to go.

```
#derp {...}
#derp:hover {...}
#derp:active {...}
#derp.pressed {...}
```

Or we do using different selectors.

**Question: Is there is default functionality in ruby on rails.**

**Update:**
I am using ajax based form submission and when i try to click 2-3 times form submittion quickly. Its actually submitted 2-3 times. I want to prevent that thing and I am using simple_form

```
<%= f.button :submit, "Submit Review", :disable_with => "Processing..." %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make [:disable_with](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag) Work with Ajax Remote You have to edit your [public/javascripts/rails.js and change](http://www.seanbehan.com/rails-3-disable_with-does-not-work-with-ajax-remote-form_for)

```
document.on("ajax:after", "form", function(event, element) {
```

to

```
document.on("ajax:complete", "form", function(event, element) {
```

Comment: I am using ajax based form submission and when i try to click 2-3 times form submittion quickly. Its actually submitted 2-3 times. I want to prevent that thing. and I am using simple_form

Comment: Any thought on where this js file would be located in Rails 4?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:disable_with` option:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag

Comment: I am using ajax based form submission and when i try to click 2-3 times form submittion quickly. Its actually submitted 2-3 times. I want to prevent that thing and I am using simple_form

Comment: Than you can add `data-disabled-with` option manually. See this issue: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/640